# Play and pause audio using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, xcode

I have a button with id 'button' which when clicked it disappears and plays the audio and a div containing font-awesome icons toggling between 'fa-volume-up' and 'fa-volume-mute'.

My Goal: I want to play audio when someone click on button and at the same time the div containing 'fa-volume-mute' change to 'fa-volume-up'. And when someone clicks 'fa-volume-up' button reappears.

```js
//Hide button on click
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#button').hide();
    });
    if ($('i').hasClass('fas fa-volume-up')) {
        audio.pause()
    }else{

    }
});

//toggle class
    $('#song').click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-volume-mute fas fa-volume-up');
    });
    $('i').click(function(){
        
    })

//On click Audio
    $(document).ready(function() {
  //Audio  Starts
  var audio = new Audio('/audio.mp3')
  $("#button").mousedown(function() {
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  });
  //Audio Ends
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="song">
        <div id ="sound">
            <i class="fas fa-volume-mute" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="button">Click</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Can you please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you simply need to break your desired behaviour down in to steps. Firstly, to start an `audio` element playing call `play()` on it. To stop it, call `pause()`. To change the class of the icon use `toggleClass()` or a combination of `removeClass()` and `addClass()`. To hide or show an element use `hide()` and `show()`.

From there, all you need is two event handlers, one on the button to start playing audio, change the icon and hide the button, and another on the icon itself to stop playing audio, change the icon and show the button.

Note in the example below the use of a single document.ready event handler (`jQuery($) {}`), and that all code is inside it. If you don't do this you may find that your event handlers are not bound correctly.
Also note that all logic dependent on the event handlers is within the event handler itself.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.button').click(e => {
    let $song = $(e.target).hide().closest('.song');
    $song.find('.audio')[0].play();
    $song.find('.icon').toggleClass('fa-volume-mute fa-volume-up');
  });
  
  $('.song').on('click', '.fa-volume-up', e => {
    let $song = $(e.target).closest('.song');
    $song.find('.audio')[0].pause();
    $song.find('.icon').removeClass('fa-volume-up').addClass('fa-volume-mute');
    $song.find('.button').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="song">
  <div class="sound">
    <i class="icon fas fa-volume-mute" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">Play</button>
  </div>
  <audio class="audio" src="https://webism.jp/media/jplayer/tw034.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help